# Visual Studio C#: Is it possible to autoformat the property name of a control before creation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, naming-conventions

I will try my best to word this correctly. I have to make a Windows Form in C# using Visual Studio 2019. In this form I have to create 60 textboxes. Instead of going through them manually and changing them from textbox1, textbox2, etc. I would like them to be created as tb1, tb2, etc. This concept would apply to other window controls such as buttons, groupboxes, etc.
Is it possible to do so in Visual Studio 2019 permanently?

Comment: Might be worth considering dynamic controls if there is that much repeat, that they are not given individually useful names.

Comment: A workaround is to create a User Control named `tb` and place a TextBox in it. Then set its Size to be consistent with the TextBox's. `this.Size = textBox.Size;`

Comment: Since it's WinForm, I'd just do a search & replace operation on the designer.cs file, less headache that way